# Корень вопросительных слов, отличный от "к" и "ч"

Tags: этимология

Правда ли, что исконно корень всех вопросительных слов в русском языке начинался с буквы "к" или "ч" (следствие чередования согласных к -> ч)

Comment: Корень вопросов? *Но зато нам твердо известно другое: не будь 1937 года, не было бы и лета 1941 года, в этом **корень вопроса**. [Константин Симонов. Сталин и война (1965)] *

Comment: ― И вы до сих пор не понимаете, в чем **корень вопроса**! [Г. Е. Николаева. Битва в пути (1959)]

Comment: Большевики 10 лет нарушали эти пропорции. Теперь уперлись лбом в стену: дальше нельзя. В этом **корень всех вопросов**. [«Дни: Еженедельник» (Париж), 1928]

Comment: @ М_Г тут этимологией и не пахнет

Comment: В этимологии рассматриваются слова (в том числе вопросительные) и их корни, а не вопросы. А "корень вопросов" — не этимологическое понятие.

Comment: Эта проблема кем-то изучалась, или вопрос не имеет истории?